# Apps Script: Add attachment to a mail merger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

**ISSUE:**

With the wonderful assistance of @Cooper, I was able to optimize my mail merger script using an html template ("emailEinladung.html") and a list of recipients ("terminBestaetige"). Each recipient gets a personalized email based on the html template, as long as his/her status in the 11th column (so, "K") is not set to "EMAIL SENT". Now I want to add one or more attachments to every email being sent.

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:**

```
function terminEinladungVersendenWithAttachments() {
  // variables to reference the sheet and its content
  const anrede = 2;
  const nachname = 3;
  const emailAdresse = 5;
  const terminTag = 6;
  const terminUhrzeit = 8;
  const terminURL = 9;
  let emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailEinladung');
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("terminBestaetigen");

  // variables for "Betreff" (in English: "subject") coming from the google Sheet named "Vorlagen"
  var wsVorlagen = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Vorlagen");
  var betreff = wsVorlagen.getRange("B1").getValue();

  const sr = 3;//start row of data
  const data = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 11).getValues();
  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    if (row[10] == "EMAIL NOT SENT YET") {
      emailTemp.anrede1 = (row[anrede]);
      emailTemp.nachname1 = (row[nachname]);
      emailTemp.emailAdresse1 = (row[emailAdresse]);
      emailTemp.terminTag1 = (row[terminTag]);
      emailTemp.terminUhrzeit1 = (row[terminUhrzeit]);
      emailTemp.terminURL1 = (row[terminURL]);
  // including attachements to each email being sent.
      var attachment1 = DriveApp.getFileById("[FILE_ID1]")
      var attachment2 = DriveApp.getFileById("[FILE_ID2]")
      var blob1 = attachment1.getBlob()
      var blob2 = attachment2.getBlob()
      var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(row[emailAdresse],
        betreff, "Dies ist eine Nachricht im HTML-Format. Sie müßen Ihre Email-Software entsprechend einrichten.",
        { htmlBody: htmlMessage, replyTo: "f.dore@skillgainer.de", attachments: [blob1, blob2]});
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 11).setValue("EMAIL SENT");//stops emails from being sent again
    }
  });
}
```

**QUESTION:**

Is there anything I should improve in my script to make it more efficient? If yes, what would that improvement be and how would YOUR script look like?

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `more efficient` you expect? Can I ask you about the current issue of your script?

Comment: @Tanaike: Thanks for getting in touch. The script works fine, in the sense that it can send out emails with attachment to each recipient on my google sheet list. But as soon as the list gets longer (so, contains more than 500 recipients!), the execution time of the script gets longer. That´s why the question: Is there a way to re-write the script, so that it can run faster? Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, I thought that `blob1` and `blob2` can be put out of the loop. I think that by this, the process cost might be a bit low. But, when 500 emails are sent, this process cost will be high. So I tested for reducing the cost for this situation. But unfortunately, I cannot still find it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But when I found it, I would like to answer it.

Comment: I thought of a workaround for reducing the process cost for sending emails. So I proposed an answer as a workaround. Could you please confirm it? This method is my try. So I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your issue. I apologize for this. So please test my proposed script. When that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, I thought that `blob1` and `blob2` can be put out of the loop. I think that by this, the process cost might be a bit low.
- But, when 500 emails are sent by `GmailApp.sendEmail` in a loop, this process cost will be high. I thought that this cost is larger than that of the above point.
- In order to reduce the process cost for sending 500 emails, in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose using Gmail API and the batch request. But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your issue. So please test the following script.

The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please install [a Google Apps Script library of BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install). You can see how to install this library at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install).

And, [please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

And please set the file IDs of `[FILE_ID1]` and `[FILE_ID2]`.

```js
const convert_ = ({ to, subject, textBody, htmlBody, attachmentfile1, attachmentfile2 }) => {
  const boundary1 = "boundaryboundary001";
  const boundary2 = "boundaryboundary002";
  const mailData = [
    `MIME-Version: 1.0`,
    `To: ${to}`,
    `Subject: =?UTF-8?B?${Utilities.base64Encode(subject, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)}?=`,
    `Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=${boundary1}`,
    ``,
    `--${boundary1}`,
    `Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=${boundary2}`,
    ``,
    `--${boundary2}`,
    `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`,
    ``,
    textBody,
    `--${boundary2}`,
    `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`,
    `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`,
    ``,
    Utilities.base64Encode(htmlBody, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8),
    `--${boundary2}--`,
    `--${boundary1}`,
    `Content-Type: image/png; charset=UTF-8; name="sample1.png"`,
    `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`,
    ``,
    attachmentfile1,
    `--${boundary1}`,
    `Content-Type: image/png; charset=UTF-8; name="sample2.png"`,
    `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`,
    ``,
    attachmentfile2,
    `--${boundary1}--`,
  ].join("\r\n");
  return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(mailData);
};

// Please run this function.
function terminEinladungVersendenWithAttachments() {
  const anrede = 2;
  const nachname = 3;
  const emailAdresse = 5;
  const terminTag = 6;
  const terminUhrzeit = 8;
  const terminURL = 9;
  let emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailEinladung');
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("terminBestaetigen");
  var wsVorlagen = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Vorlagen");
  var betreff = wsVorlagen.getRange("B1").getValue();
  const sr = 3;
  const data = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 11).getValues();
  var attachmentfile1 = Utilities.base64Encode(DriveApp.getFileById("[FILE_ID1]").getBlob().getBytes());
  var attachmentfile2 = Utilities.base64Encode(DriveApp.getFileById("[FILE_ID2]").getBlob().getBytes());

  var {requests, sent} = data.reduce((o, row, i) => {
    if (row[10] == "EMAIL NOT SENT YET") {
      emailTemp.anrede1 = (row[anrede]);
      emailTemp.nachname1 = (row[nachname]);
      emailTemp.emailAdresse1 = (row[emailAdresse]);
      emailTemp.terminTag1 = (row[terminTag]);
      emailTemp.terminUhrzeit1 = (row[terminUhrzeit]);
      emailTemp.terminURL1 = (row[terminURL]);
      var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
      const obj = {
        to: row[emailAdresse],
        subject: betreff,
        textBody: "Dies ist eine Nachricht im HTML-Format. Sie müßen Ihre Email-Software entsprechend einrichten.",
        htmlBody: htmlMessage,
        attachmentfile1, attachmentfile2
      };
      o.requests.push({method: "POST", endpoint: "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send", requestBody: { raw: convert_(obj) }});
      o.sent.push("K" + (i + 3));
    }
    return o;
  }, {requests: [], sent: []});
  if (sent.length > 0) sh.getRangeList(sent).setValue("EMAIL SENT");
  const res = BatchRequest.EDo({ batchPath: "batch/gmail/v1", accessToken: ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(), requests: requests });
  console.log(res)
}
```

#### Note:

- This method is my try. So please test the above script.

#### References:

- [Batching Requests for Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)
- [BatchRequest of Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)
- [Method: users.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I´ve asked a new question about a different issue. Would you mind having a look at it? Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69613959/apps-script-how-to-convert-english-date-format-to-german-date-format. Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @Bob Hardball Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to check it. When I could find the solution, I would like to answer it.