# Apps Script: How to convert English date format to German date format?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am pretty sure this is a small issue, but I just can´t figure out how to solve it, as I am new at using Apps script :(.

**ISSUE:**

I have a sheets consisting of 2 columns: A and B. The column A contains dates written in German format (**Day/Month/Year**). Example: October 18th, 2021 is written 18/10/2021. Now all I want to do is increment each day from column A by 1 day and write the outcome (so, the incremented days) in column B.

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:**

I´ve figured out how to increment the days and write the outcome in column B. But I am struggling to add the second part of my script, so that the incremented dates are written in German in column B (See scripts below).

**QUESTION:**

How and where can I include the “Utilities.formatDate()” into my code, so that the dates in column B are formatted in German? (So, **DAY/MONTH/YEAR** instead of MONTH/DAY/YEAR)?

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

```
// Increment dates in colum A by 1 day and write this incremented date in colum B
function incrementDateInGermanFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = new Date(ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue());
  ss.getRange(1, 2).setValue(new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)));
}

// This is the line I´m having trouble to include in the script above
Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: see cross-site duplicate https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62586/how-to-format-the-date-in-this-google-apps-script

Comment: @Kos - Thanks for the hint. I´ve tried many variations of the code on that link... in vain. Is there anything else you could recommend me that´s more in line with the specificity of my issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bad practice to convert date to strings. In this case, a better alternative is to simply change column B's date  format to german in the spreadsheet user interface or use [`.setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy")`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) on column B.

Comment: The dates in column A are already EXACTLY the way I want them: in German format (So, DAY/MONTH/YEAR). I want this German format to stay/not change, when the dates are incremented in column B. Now the question is: how and where can i add the setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy" that you just recommende me? Thanks :)

Comment: @BobHardball First, Why can't you change it in the user interface? Select column B> Number > formatting

Comment: When I do what you recommended me (so, use the user interface to format the values in column B), I get "1/1/1970" in each cell. Therefore my initial question again: Do you or anybody know how and where I can add this to to my final script? "Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy")". Thanks :)

Comment: @BobHardball No. Go back. Don't bandage the issue. Treat it at it's source. If you get "1/1/1970", it simply means the new date that you're setting is wrong, which probably means the date you're getting from column A is wrong. Dates should be put as dates in spreadsheet. What is the type of column A? For eg, what's the output of `=TYPE(A1)`. See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375 or `=ISDATE(A1)`

Comment: The outcome of "=ISDATE(A1)" is TRUE. That´s the result I get.

Comment: @BobHardball then log `date` in your script and see if it is as expected. `var date = new Date(ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue()); console.log(date)`

Comment: The log for var "var date = new Date(ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue()); console.log(date)" is "Mon Oct 18 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)".

Comment: Not sure what's going on. But try changing your locale to germany in [google](https://accounts.google.com/language)  and in File>Spreadsheet settings at the very last. If all else fails, the bandage: `var newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)));var newFormattedDate = Utilties.formatDate(newDate,Session.getScriptTimezone(), "dd/MM/yyyy"); ss.getRange(1,2).setValue(newFormattedDate)`

Comment: outcome after addind and running the code snippet you sent me: "ReferenceError: Utilties is not defined".

Comment: @Bob Typo. Check  the correct spelling `Utilities` in official reference or code editor auto complete

Comment: outcome after correcting the spelling ("Utilities" instead of "Utilties": "TypeError: Session.getScriptTimezone is not a function". Getting a little bit desperate over here :(

Comment: @Bob Just copy  that line from your  original post. Another typo: `Session.getScriptTimeZone`. Uppercase `Z`. I didn't check for typo... Check your code editor. If it underlines anything in red, check the spelling

Comment: I finally figured out what was wrong: 1) the dates that are already written in column A must be in English format (so, MONTH/DAY/YEAR), in order for the script to write these dates in German format (so, DAY/MONTH/YEAR in column B, and 2) in the variable "var newDate" that you sent me, there was one unnecessary quoration mark. The whole script now works perfectly fine, BUT: the dates in column A are coming automatically from a German calendar as DAY/MONTH/YEAR, and would love to keep them in that format in column A. Any idea how to solve this last remaining issue? Thanks :)

Comment: @BobHardball Did you check your Google account language settings and File>Spreadsheet settings as I've said before?

Comment: I did check the spreadsheet settings. I cannot change them from U.S. to Germany, because A) I need my current U.S.-settings on a regular basis and B) the calendar providing dates to column A is a German calendar... unfortunately :(

Comment: @BobHardball `(1) the dates that are already written in column A must be in English format`. I'm sure this is not a issue as long as it is a valid date(`=ISDATE(A1)` outputs true). Change column A format to a custom date format with `dd/mm/yyyy` in Number> Format. Where is the date coming from? Are you typing it manually in? Consider asking a new question with relevant details for this.

Comment: The dates in colum A are coming AUTOMATICALLY from the datepicker of materialize.com and already formatted in German (so, DAY/MONTH/YEAR). And honestly would rather leave them in this format and stay focused on what matters the most: Get the same format (so, DAY/MONTH/YEAR) in colum B after incrementing each date in that column B by 1 day, as initially stated in my opening question. Any idea how to achieve this final goal? I mean we´ve come so far and should be able to go this extra mile, right? Thanks :)

Comment: **@TheMaster** - After nearly 2 hours of going through ALL your recommendations and double-checking my script, I finally realized that you were right all along about changing the settings of the spreadsheet instead of trying to re-invent the wheel. Yeah, changing the settings was the key. Thank you soooo much, **@TheMaster**!!!!